# I plan to use this approach to do something or doing something

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

I know if we say "This is an approach to doing something" we should use "to doing" after approach.
In the case "I plan to use this approach ", should I say "to do" or "to doing" something?

Comment: Both are right in their own places.  to do/ to go etc. are infinitives but in 'to doing', to precedes a verbal noun.  It's like "We look forward to receive you...and......to receiving you." Both are in vogue. It's just that the user should understand this difference.

Comment: I'm struggling with the precise grammar of "I plan to use this approach to do something", but I think there are two different cases. In this, "to do something" is more like an adverbial expressing purpose (modifying "use"), rather than specifically modifying "approach". In contrast, in a phrase like "my approach to playing the guitar", "playing the guitar" clearly attaches to "approach".